# Webpack HMR with React Native

Tags: react-native, webpack, watchman

Is there a recent Webpack HMR react-native boilerplate out there?

I am having trouble finding a best practice for integrating an existing setup with Webpack and HMR to be used with react-native and the react-native packager. The resources I found online on this topic are dated.

- I know that it uses Facebook's `watchman`.
- I also know of the [webpack-watchman-plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/webpack-watchman-plugin), but I don't think that will allow me to trigger a webpack build and serve the compiled assets to react-native. I know that watchman has [-- trigger](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html#simple-syntax)  functionality, but don't think digging in the packager local CLI is the answer either.

I'm at a loss for finding decent documentation for Facebook's packager, and not sure where to get started on this. My goal is to take an existing boilerplate used for web React, and use the boilerplate setup for react-native. I understand about the rendering differences, this is mostly the build tool part.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue by not trying to integrate webpack with react-native, but by not using webpack at all and using react-native's `packager`. Still working on it, but I like it so far! Using it for my Open-Source react-native boilerplate project, [strangeluv-native](https://github.com/wswoodruff/strangeluv-native)